# Шапка для сайта

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте! У меня есть шапка сайта, сделана как страница. Когда я его вставляю в index страницу, происходит нечто непонятное. Я вставляю с помощью инклюд. Весь дизайн сайта портится. Что делать, чтоб дизайн не испортился? Если что, могу отправить архив с файлами.

Comment: вы бы файлики выложили где-нибудь для скачивания... или хотя бы код минимально написали.

Answer (score 1):

Между тегами `<head></head>` убедитесь, что все стили прописываются через слэш, т.е. `/style.css`, например:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
```

Answer (score -1):

шапка должна размещаться в тегах <head></head>
При этом шапка не должна быть как страница, а в виде картинки с вложенными скриптами. Потому у вас и ошибка